# how to check the current directory on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

Sorry for the naive question.

(I am now studying CS61B from UCB. The problem is I've never used linux or Unix before and all their instructions are written for those systems..)

So I don't know how to get started....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pwd` will show you the current directory.

Comment: Unfortunately it shows you a relative directory from within cygwin, what if you need the full directory from within windows?

Comment: How about this `pwd | xargs cygpath -w`? See the help of `cygpath` for more path format options.

Comment: @JohnChain very good, that works, thanks.